# Orchard - custom module not showing up

Tags: orchardcms

I created a custom module. It showed up on dashboard "Modules", and I was able to enable it. But I don't see the new content type under "New" or under "Content". Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Or how can I debug this issue?

Thanks.